# $\tan(x)$ with phase shift and period

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to transform $$y=A \tan(Bx-C)+D$$ so that there are two consecutive vertical asymptotes at $x=17$ and $x=19$.

I want the period to equal $2$ and so I set $B=\pi/2$.  I want a vertical asymptote at $17$ so I set $17+\pi/2=(2\times c)/\pi$. I get $$y=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{19-17}x-\frac{2\times17\times\pi+\pi^2}{2(19-17)}\right)$$  But this isn't working according to [**an online graphing engine**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+tan+%28%5Bpi%2F%2819-17%29%5Dx-%5B%28%5B2%2a17%2api%5D%2B%5Bpi%5E2%5D%29%2F%282%2a%2819-17%29%29%5D%29+from+x%3D16.5+to+x%3D19.5).

Any help on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In the third line you want asymptotes at $x=17,19$, then later you say you want one at $17+2\pi$.  Which is it?

Comment: I want the asymptote at 17.  I'll correct that, sorry.

Comment: If you set $B$ as you did, then taking $C=0$ gives you vertical asymptote at $17$.

Comment: I see that it works now but I thought that I would at least need to shift the vertical asymptote at $x=-\pi/2$ to $x=17$.  With $C=0$ I am calculating (incorrectly I suppose) that the v.a.'s are at $-.5\pi,1.5\pi,...,15.5\pi,17.5\pi$. So how is there now a v.a. at $x=17$?

Comment: Here is my thought process, in hopes of understanding better.  I set $B=\pi/2$ so that the period would be $2$.  So then I have $y=\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}x-C)$ and I want to get the shift right.  If I shift it so there is a v.a. at $x=1$ I will be fine, so I get into standard form, i.e. $y=\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}(x-\frac{C}{\pi/2})$.  If I shift my graph $(3\pi)/2$ it will work, so I set $(3\pi)/2=\frac{C}{\pi/2}$ in order to find $C$.  But this gives me $C=(3/4)*\pi^2$, which actually doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asymptotes at $17,19$, you have one at $1$ and a zero at $0$.  So $\tan \frac \pi 2 x$ should work.  Here is the [Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20tan%20%28x%20pi/2%29%20for%20x%20from%2014%20to%2020)